# Consistent union of months into a quarter, half year, year

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I have an array of Deposits (first column)

```
data class Deposit(val term: Int, val termType String, val rate BigDecimal)
```

I tried to divide the array into blocks of 3 elements in order to combine 1 month into one quarter (assuming the same rate), but in other cases it is more convenient to take 2 elements, although in this case the union may not occur correctly. 2nd and 3rd quarter are merged into half a year.

Tell me how you can, albeit not in an optimal way, recursively perform a sequential conversion of months into a quarter, half a year and a year.

Example:

| Input | Step 1..N | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 month – 6% | 1 quarter — 6% | 1 quarter — 6% |
| 1 month – 6% |  |  |
| 1 month – 6% |  |  |
| 3 month – 5% | 1 quarter – 5% | 1 quarter – 5% |
| 3 month – 5% | 1 quarter – 5% | 1 quarter – 5% |
| 3 month – 3% | 1 quarter – 3% | 1 quarter – 3% |
| 3 month – 6% | 1 half a year – 6% | 1 year – 6% |
| 3 month – 6% |  |  |
| 3 month – 6% | 1 half a year – 6% |  |
| 3 month – 6% |  |  |
| 3 month – 7% | 1 half a year – 7% | 1 half a year – 7% |
| 3 month – 7% |  |  |
| 3 month – 8% | 1 half a year – 8% | 1 half a year – 8% |
| 3 month – 8% |  |  |

I tried to divide the array into blocks of 3 elements in order to combine 1 month into one quarter (assuming the same rate), but in other cases it is more convenient to take 2 elements, although in this case the union may not occur correctly. 2nd and 3rd quarter are merged into half a year.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot understand. How do I read your example? Is it one example or one example per row? Why are there no month numbers or month names in your data? Is `termType` relevant, and if so, what is it?

Comment: One example per row. Term: 1, TermType: month, Rate: 6%

Comment: So *Term: 1, TermType: month, Rate: 6%* would mean January, am i starting to get some of it? And val 2 termType Quarter qould mean Q2, so April through June?? Which year? I suppose I need to know the year before I can combine them into years?

Comment: Can you have an input Deposit that's *2* months, or is everything *1* and *3*? And if you have four *1-month* Deposits in a row, should that become one *1-quarter* and one *1-month*? Can a *1-quarter* term start after any number of months, or does it have to be after a multiple of three, e.g. so it aligns with a fiscal quarter? Combining the items isn't complicated, but the rules about *how* you need them to be combined might be